# Restricting aws resource to a specific ecs cluster

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs, distributed-computing

I have 2 ecs clusters both running the same service but only of them is supposed to access some aws resource(lambda/ sqs). How can this be achieved ? Also, I need some mechanism to trigger a piece of code/ function in service (java) in that cluster only from lambda. Considering both clusters code is same, how can this be achieved too ?

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the canonical way to achieve it is by using a `Task Role` and associate it to the task that underpins the service that needs to access the AWS resources. You essentially craft a specific IAM role that has access to the resources you need to access and specify it in the task definition. Containers launched by that task definition will have access locally to AWS temporary credentials that will allow your code to access those resources. Because the code (container image?) is the same, you want to have two separate task definitions that are exactly the same but for one having the task role and the other not having it. Your two services will continue to be identical but one will have temporary creds and the other will not. More info [here in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html).

The second part of the question is a bit vague (and possibly answers could be very opinionated as John pointed out).